# Which is the best data structure for performing calculations involving very large digits

Tags: data-structures

suppose the operation needs to be performed is A*(B/C) where A,B,C are digits greater than 10,0000.Int and long can't store numbers after a certain limit.so, for operations on numbers bigger than these which is the best data structure.

Comment: You'll need to specify which language you are using. Some languages have built-in support for massive integers, others have core math/crypto libraries supporting them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to implement big-integer support in general, you'll often be using an array (or possibly a bit vector or an array of integers or even a string) to store the digits and then using various tricks to perform arithmetic operations 'keyhole-style'.

Comment: Also: depending on the use case a binary or a decimal representation might be more natural.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your language,

java: BigInteger

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

.net: BigInteger (Has been introduced recently in .net 4)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

Other languages/platforms: something is probably available either built in or via 3rd party libraries. Try looking for "BigInteger". I don't think you will ever have to implement this data structure yourself unless you really want to.